# in angularjs, how to filter array by a property which contains expression

Tags: angularjs, filter

Assume there is an array:
[{name: 'a', display: 'obj.a==="1"}, {name: 'b', display: true}]
Is it possible to filter the array by the property display's real value?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {};
  $scope.arr  = [{name: 'a', display: 'obj.a==="1"'}, {name: 'b', display: true}];
}])

        ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.a">
    <div>
      <span ng-repeat="item in arr|filter:{display: true}">{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still cant understand can u explain once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you. Good luck

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.a">
    <div>
      <span ng-repeat="item in arr|regex:'display':regex_check">{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.regex_check = '"[1]"';
   $scope.obj = {};
   $scope.arr  = [{name: 'a', display: 'obj.a==="1"'}, {name: 'b', display: true}];
 }])
 
 app.filter('regex', function() {
   return function(input, field, regex) {
    var patt = new RegExp(regex);      
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     if(patt.test(input[i][field]))
      out.push(input[i]);
    }
  return out;
   };
 });
</script>
```